# 301 Redirects from old Wordpress domain

Tags: redirect

I have an old site www.exemple.com and I made a new one name www.example.ro
The thing is, the old site (and the new one) are Woocommerce shops and have a lot of products. Is there any method to perform this redirects automatically? Or at least to configure all of them at once? If so, how?
Thank you!

Comment: Are the new site and old site in the same structure?

Comment: The product names are the same. I have to change the URL before products, but that's not the main problem.
I think I will use Redirections plugin on the old site and setup the following rule:

Source URL: https://example.com
Query Parameters: "Ignore & pass parameters to the target"
Target URL: https://example.ro

That will direct all traffic from the .com to the .co.

Comment: If your http server is apache you can use redirect either in .htaccess or in the <virtualhost> block - "Redirect 301 / https://example.ro/" or for nginx within server block "return 301 https://example.ro$request_uri;"

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what http server you are using so I'll assume it is either Apache or Nginx.

**Apache**

The most efficient method would be to include a "redirect" statement within the  block;

```
<VirtualHost your_ip_address:80>

ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com

Redirect 301 / https://example.ro/

</VirtualHost>
```

By doing it within your httpd.conf the work is done prior to any site resources being served. It will effectively take all traffic for example.com to example.ro as soon as it is requested.

Another method, again for Apache, is via the .htaccess file. This method requires you place a .htaccess file into each sub-directory because URLs like example.com/wp-admin would still succeed without redirection.

Your .htaccess in the root folder for your domain needs the following added.

```
Redirect 301 / https://example.ro/
```

After modifying Apache's config restart it and the changes will be effective immediately.

**Nginx**

Nginx is just as simple although it does not support .htaccess files. The redirection is performed within the Server block.

For example;

server {
    listen your_ip_address:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

```
return 301 https://example.ro$request_uri;
```

}

Reload Nginx and the redirection will become active.

**Browser Cache**

Clear your browser cache otherwise you might have issues. Google Chrome drives me mental when I make a change and it doesn't care until I clean the cache, curse & swear at it and try again.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
My sites are not really in the same structure. 
How should I proceed in order to resolve this? Change the structure of the new site?

Comment: For the method I suggested they don't need to be in the same structure. To verify it worked I did a redirect from one url to another for one of my sites and it worked perfectly. Although they were both on the same server they were completely different and separate domains. It should work for you.

Comment: Yes, the method works. 
But let's assume that I have something like this:
oldwebsite.com/products/jeans/product-name
new website.ro/example/jeans/product-name
Product names are the same in most cases. I want this because when people are googling the website, I don't want just to be redirected to the new site. I want them to be redirected to the same page as structure, but in the new site.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood. I'm not an expert on .htaccess files but I believe it will do a rewrite & redirect as you require. For example, example.com/products/air-guitar-with-case becomes example.ro/products/air-guitar-with-case. Is that closer to what you're asking?

Comment: Are you nginx or apache? The nginx option I offered does exactly what you want I believe because it only changes the domain, the rest of the url remains the same.

Comment: I am on Apache. I will try to configure the new site on the same structure and do as you mentioned. Hope it will work

Comment: Sorry I can't help further. I'm not an expert in .htaccess, although there are thousands of examples around through google. Perhaps this question is more suited on https://serverfault.com/ which is where all the server guys are. Doing redirects through wordpress would be resource hungry and very slow. Best to be done at the server level. Wish I could help you further. :(